# Change hover blue color of top menu using CSS / jQuery

Tags: html, css

I am trying to change the blue hover color of top menu to black on my website using CSS / jQuery:

[image: Image of a horizontal menu]

I have written following code:

```
<style>
#menu-top:hover { color: #000 }
.nav-menu:hover { color: #000 }
</style>
```

But it does not change the color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two problems

1. you are using `color` which changes text color instead of `background-color`
2. you are trying to change the entire navbar when hovered, instead of the elements. Use a [combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors#combinators) to match the elements you want, for example, `.nav-menu *:hover` matches any element that is a descendent of the navbar (this seems to work on this site)

So the final might look like

```html
<style>
#menu-top *:hover { background-color: #000 }
.nav-menu *:hover { background-color: #000 }
</style>
```